# Multithread server doesn't work

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am writing simple client server program in Qt that server is multi thread. 
For one server it work correctly and it can send message from client to server but in multi thread form it doesn't work, it connect to thread and also show the message "client connected" but it can't show message sent from client!
I searched a lot bud I couldn't find what is the problem and any solution for it.. Here is my code:
Could you please help me. Thanks in advance.

myserver.cpp

```
#include "myserver.h"
#include "mythread.h"

myserver::myserver(QObject * parent):  QTcpServer(parent)
{
}

void myserver::startserver()
{
    int port = 6666;
    if (!this - > listen(QHostAddress::Any, port)) {
        qDebug() << "Could not start server ";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Listening to port ";
    }
}

void myserver::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor) 
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";

    mythread * thread = new mythread(socketDescriptor, this);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    thread - > start();
}
```

mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include "myserver.h"

mythread::mythread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
}

void mythread::run()
{
    qDebug() << " Thread started";

    socket = new QTcpSocket();

    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor)) {
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSocket()));

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Client connected";
}

void mythread::readSocket()
{
    QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

    qDebug()<< socketDescriptor <<" Data in: " << Data;

    socket->write(Data);
}
```

Comment: Off-topic. We won't debug your code or doo your homework. Did you compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [documentation for the `QThread::run` function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run) you will see

> Returning from this method will end the execution of the thread.

You need to call the [`QThread::exec`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exec) function to enter the thread event loop.

Comment: @Hanita If this answer fixes your problem, consider *accepting* it. Same with all of your older questions, go through them and if you have an answer that fixes the problem you asked about and that you used then accept that. Please read ["How does accepting an answer work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).